# Generic access to C data structures in C++ via some form of reflection?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, testing, reflection

Is there a reflection framework for accessing C/C++ data structures (nested structs, arrays of pointers, various other basic data types) in a generic way?

If not, any hints to best approach this?

I'm writing test software for [a large MS Windows C API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CEN/XFS) with tens to hundreds of different structs, some of which contain nested array of pointers to structs up to several levels.

For the tests the data structures need to be preset with values and checked afterwards, according to test descriptions given as strings.  Currently this is programmed in a rather flat and tedious (and inconsistent and error-prone) way, which I'd like to change.

I'm thinking of some templates for all the data type constructions used that allow to access the values in the data structures generically via some kind of paths.

I don't need this to be fully automated, it would be OK to do some work (say one or two lines of code) for each specific field in a struct.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. The generic way to access a member of a C data structure is with the dot or arrow operator. (`fooStruct.someMember`) Or do you mean you want some kind of reflection, like `getMember(typeof(FooStruct), "someMember")`?

Comment: Can you give an example of a "test description"?

Comment: Yes, reflection would do, I updated the tags accordingly.  I'm even prepared to do some of the per-structure work required.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing a feature called reflection, which C/C++ don't support.

The way to do this in C++ would be to parse the source files and then generate more source code to perform the operations you require, e.g. find each class, and nested classes, find each member function, etc.

Writing a C++ parser is hard but there are lots of existing free implementations available.

Comment: I think doing the access and setting it up for the specific data structures via parsing are separate issues.  For now I don't think I can justify parsing, even though parsing plain C would probably suffice.

Comment: In a language with a reflection-capable runtime, you would be correct, because then you would have an excellent alternative to parsing. But for C and C++, I think you are mistaken: there is no way to discover the "shape" of a type at runtime unless you do your own examination of the source code. Within the language, the best you can do is discover the static size of a time with the `sizeof` operator, which will only help with discovering the length of arrays, assuming they have a statically declared length.

Comment: "Doing the access" is trivial once you know what you will be accessing. The actual problem is finding out what to access.